# Fast RSA-SHA1 implementation for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, rsa, sha

As part of a NodeJS application, I'm regularly generating signed AWS CloudFront URLs. When a lot of simultaneous requests hit the server, I've noticed a performance bottleneck in our application during the generation of the signature. Specifically, the function from aws-cloudfront-sign [here](https://github.com/jasonsims/aws-cloudfront-sign/blob/master/lib/cloudfrontUtil.js#L157):

```
function _createPolicySignature(policy, privateKey) {
    var sign = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA1');
    sign.update(policy.toJSON());

    return sign.sign(privateKey, 'base64');
}
```

Profiling the node app gives the following output:

```
 ticks parent  name
21043   98.4%  UNKNOWN
 1775    8.4%    LazyCompile: *_createPolicySignature node_modules\aws-cloudfront-sign\lib\cloudfrontUtil.js:157:32
 1775  100.0%      LazyCompile: ~getSignedUrl node_modules\aws-cloudfront-sign\lib\cloudfrontUtil.js:19:22
 1363   76.8%        LazyCompile: *getCDNDownloadURL
 1363  100.0%          LazyCompile: *getImageObject
 1305   95.7%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous>
   58    4.3%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous>
  412   23.2%        LazyCompile: ~getCDNDownloadURL
  206   50.0%          LazyCompile: ~getImageObject
  206  100.0%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous>
  206   50.0%          LazyCompile: *getImageObject
  179   86.9%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous>
   27   13.1%            LazyCompile: ~<anonymous>
```

I'm looking for ways to improve this. Is there a library I can use which will perform better in this case? The private key always remains the same, so maybe something which doesn't have to create new signing objects / buffers each time it is used? Unfortunately, as the profiler only gives an `UNKNOWN` for the code inside the `crypto` library, I'm not sure where the exact bottleneck is occurring. Is there a way to get the profiller to also show the stack trace when calling NodeJS libraries?

Comment: I am a complete novice in the crypto world, but would using [`sign.write()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_sign) (which treats the Sign object as a stream) perform better?

Comment: Unfortunately not I don't think - looking at the crypto source code in node, `sign.write()` just does the same thing as `sign.update()` internally.